# Is there a way for iSeries AS400 sessions not get disconnected or locked

Tags: authentication, ibm-midrange

I have to deal with this in a daily basis:

For some reason, maybe due to input error, our users get their sessions disconnected from our iSeries AS400 and I have to manually enter the command:

```
WRKCFGSTS *DEV SESSIONAME
```

and change it to status `VARY ON PENDING`

Is there a way for our AS400 to accept connections no matter what circumstance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is not accidental, it is a deliberate security setting.  Say you have a terminal in a public space.  If a visitor decides to try random user profile / password combinations, the system can be configured to disable the profile and device.  The idea then is that the administrator would check the log and see what is happening before simply varying the device back on.  WRKSYSVAL QMAXSGNACN to see the current setting.  A companion system value is QMAXSIGN - if this is set too low, the end users may be disabling themselves too easily.

There are other settings which tell the system whether to automatically configure devices or not.  See the system values QAUTOCFG and QAUTOVRT.

You really should check the system history log (DSPLOG QHST) as well as the system operator message queue (DSPMSG QSYSOPR) to see why the devices are being varied off.

Comment: I understand the setting, but we don't have public terminals and the network itself is access controlled. That was the setting I was looking for, Thank you very much.